# Would I be able to disable parts of 1.17 update?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been seeing a lot of the 1.17 snapshots, and I am a huge fan of the Cliffs parts of the update, but I think the new caves would be very annoying and hard to light up. Would I be able to download the 1.17 update but disable the new cave generations. Ideally, I would disable all cave generation, but probably keep ravines to help me out early game. The idea is that I would no longer have to light up caves, or when I am mining for diamonds, I would not have to bridge across or deal with lava. (I am pretty sure that lava generation is tied to cave generation.)

Comment: I know this kind of sounds like cheating, but I think they just get in the way A LOT when I am mining or trying to do things.

Comment: it seems your problem is that you wouldn't be able to see in caves, and you are looking for a solution to that, yes?

Comment: Kind of, I just don't want any caves at all. It would help with things like mob farms and such.

Comment: i know a workaround to get normal caves and tall mountains, although its not exactly what you want. Its also of note that 1.17 wont have any new terrain generation due to the update split.

Comment: I heard about that, but I figured that when part 2 comes I would like to disable it, or even disable the current caves we have now.

Comment: So you should be talking about 1.18, which has no snapshots yet. I say this is off-topic

Comment: Yes, the second part will be in 1.18, but I added that I would like to disable the current cave generation in 1.16. I planned on then using the information to, when 1.18 comes, disable the new cave generations.

Comment: @Big_Chungus Could you add your motivations and your actual request (can/how do I modify or disable cave generation?) to the question by editing it instead of as comments? Use the Edit button below your question (see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/editing). This question by itself lacks details and clarity which is attracting close votes and downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround 1: Fullbright

In your video settings in minecraft there is a brightness slider, you can go into the file storing this and change it to a really high number, so you will always be able to see with no light.

Workaround 2: amplified world

Download the latest minecraft snapshot and open it. Click on create new world -> more world settings -> world type -> amplified

This will give you massive mountains and the *normal small cave generation, with all 1.17 features currently released in snapshots.

*It is currently unknown if it will be possible to disable the new cave gen in 1.18, and in the snapshots with cave gen features there was no built in way, so i assume datapacks will be needed upon 1.18's release

Comment: Thank you, but since the mobs will still spawn it doesn't help with everything, and I watched a couple of videos with the caves from the snapshot in them, and now that I think about it, it would be best to keep them, as I can go around finding exposed diamonds initially while lighting it up, and as far as mining goes, there's really not that much lava, so I could just deal with it like the nether because the caves really are quite beautiful. I think it would be best to keep the game as vanilla-ish as possible if I want to call it Minecraft.

Comment: @Big_Chungus then what are you really asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Using Fullbright or world type Amplified is a good workaround, or keep stacks of torches on you at all times to keep the game as vanilla-ish as possible to feel more legit. (Coal and wood are easy to find, so you will have plenty of materials to make torches, considering the recipe makes ***4*** of them.)